# Deduplicate image files

Tags: images, checksum, duplicate

```
[user@notebook foobar]$ ls *.jpg|wc -l
1959
[user@notebook foobar]$ cksum * | cut -d' ' -f-2 | sort | uniq -di | wc -l
698
[user@notebook foobar]$
```

There are many jpg files in a directory. 
Many of the files are duplicates, but I can spot them out if the cksum is the same for them. 
Sometimes there are 2 or 3 file of the same picture.

**Q:** How can I delete the unneeded duplicates?

I need to leave 1 from every picture, so if there are 3 exactly same pictures with different filenames, **only one of them should remain**, so there will be no duplicates of the picture, how to do this?

Comment: do you care which _filename_ remains out of a duplicate set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use fdupes:

```
fdupes -dN .
```

man fdupes:

```
   -d --delete
          prompt user for files to  preserve,  deleting  all  others  (see
          CAVEATS below)

   -N --noprompt
          when  used  together  with  --delete, preserve the first file in
          each set of duplicates and delete the others  without  prompting
          the user
```

Answer (score 0):

This script uses an associative array in bash to save checksums, then report duplicates; change the `echo` to be `rm` if it looks good (or an `rm -i` for more paranoia):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare -A sums
for f in *
do
  if [[ ! -f "$f" ]]; then continue; fi
  c=$(cksum "$f" | awk '{print $1}')
  [[ -n "${sums[$c]}" ]] && echo "# rm \"$f\" -- duplicate of ${sums[$c]}"
  sums[$c]="$f"
done
```